# Composition of free space propagation and Huygens' principle

Tags: optics, huygens-principle

With paraxial approximation, the free space propagation operator with distance $d$ boils down to
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{R}_df)(x,y)= \frac{e^{jkd}}{j\lambda d}\iint e^{-j\frac{k}{2d}((x-x')^2+(y-y')^2)}f(x',y')\,dx'dy'.
\end{align}
It can be shown that $\mathcal{R}_{d_1}\mathcal{R}_{d_2}=\mathcal{R}_{d_1+d_2}$ by routine calculation (my reference is Goodman's "Introduction to Fourier Optics"). In my humble opinion, it is rather intuitive when we dissect the propagation with distance $d_1+d_2$ into two parts, which basically invokes Huygens' principle and superposition principle. What puzzling me is that it seems no longer true when we do not apply paraxial approximation; precisely, for
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{R}_d'f)(x,y)= \iint \frac{e^{jk\sqrt{d^2+(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}}}{j\lambda \sqrt{d^2+(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}} f(x',y')\,dx'dy'.
\end{align}
Is my understanding correct? If so, how can we make it right by tweaking some bits?

Comment: why would you expect the *near-field terms* to satisfy the energy conservation in a wave propagation rule?

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for the comment. But I do not understand what you mean as what I only know is almost physics 101. Could you elaborate on it or suggest me a material such as textbook?

Comment: With the "square root" in the integrand you are also including effects that are only within a couple of wavelengths to the edge of "obstruction" (slot, lens, mirror, etc.). These do not propagate. Only terms $\mathcal {O}(r^{-1})$ propagate but there are also (1) $\mathcal {O}(r^{-3})$ and (2) $\mathcal {O}(r^{-2})$, (1) corresponds to the static field of a dipole while (2) to an inducted (Faraday) field, these do not propagate but rather stay around the obstacle and form the "near field".